# Lisp sorting query

Tags: lisp, elisp, common-lisp

I want to sort ((A 4) (B 2) (C 3) (D 5)) such that the result would be ((D 5) (A 4) (C 3) (B 2)). I have trier the normal sort technique but it does not apply to sublists.

Comment: Please add your code to the question. You'll more likely get specific help when there's more detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing from your question that you want to sort by the number in each sublist. The sort procedure takes a keyword argument called 'key' to specify what you want to sort on[[0](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_sort_.htm)]. In this case you want to sort on the second element of each list. If the list you gave were stored in a variable called 'xs' this is how you would do it:

```
(sort xs #'> :key #'second)
```

Just be careful because sort is destructive, so what you probably want is something along the lines of:

```
(sort (copy-list xs) #'> :key #'second)
```

Edit: If you want to pair the elements you have to write a separate procedure to do that. A basic version would look something like this:

```
(defun pair (xs)
  (if (null xs)
      '()
      (cons (list (first xs) (second xs))
            (pair (rest (rest xs))))))
```

Comment: yes that's exactly right. I want to sort based on the second element in each list.

Comment: And can i know how to create a list such as ((A 4) (B 3) (C 1)).Right now my list is of the form (A 4 B 3 C 1).

Comment: Thanks malisper. It was a much needed help :)